# SQL Query - Hide lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my environment we use Altiris to control our asset and daily we had a policy that set status retired to computers that stay more than 45 days offline  and turn back to active if this computer appers online on network.

The problem is sometimes (not for all devices) when the policy change the status it write on database two lines:
first with the current status and and another with the new status:

The same occur when the device go back to active status so when i try to SUM data to know how many devices was changed to retired or active by month the number doesn't make sense because for some devices we have two lines with 2 different status on same dataChanged

eg:

```
ComputerName    Date Changed        Status
001PROJNEW-VM   13/01/2015 17:33    Active
002PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
002PROJNEW-VM   07/10/2014 21:10    Retired
002PROJNEW-VM   07/10/2014 21:10    Active
003PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
003PROJNEW-VM   13/11/2014 03:27    Retired
003PROJNEW-VM   13/11/2014 03:27    Active
004PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
005PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
005PROJNEW-VM   09/10/2014 21:09    Retired
005PROJNEW-VM   09/10/2014 21:09    Active
005PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
006PROJNEW-VM   26/12/2014 20:00    Retired
006PROJNEW-VM   31/12/2014 05:34    Retired
006PROJNEW-VM   31/12/2014 05:34    Active
006PROJNEW-VM   06/01/2015 20:00    Retired
007PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
007PROJNEW-VM   27/12/2014 05:38    Retired
007PROJNEW-VM   27/12/2014 05:38    Active
007PROJNEW-VM   12/04/2015 19:50    Retired
008PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
008PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Retired
008PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Active
008PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
009PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
009PROJNEW-VM   17/09/2014 20:33    Retired
009PROJNEW-VM   17/09/2014 20:33    Active
009PROJNEW-VM   19/02/2015 20:00    Retired
010PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
010PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Retired
010PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Active
010PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
011PROJNEW-VM   05/04/2015 20:00    Retired
013PROJNEW-VM   20/02/2015 20:00    Retired
014PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
```

Basically what i need and actually i can't do is: if the hostname has two equal 'Date Changed' and two different 'status' bring in query result the last line for this Hostname and 'Date Changed'...

The result eg:

```
Nome do computador  Date Changed    Status
001PROJNEW-VM   13/01/2015 17:33    Active
002PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
002PROJNEW-VM   07/10/2014 21:10    Active
003PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
003PROJNEW-VM   13/11/2014 03:27    Active
004PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
005PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
005PROJNEW-VM   09/10/2014 21:09    Active
005PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
006PROJNEW-VM   26/12/2014 20:00    Retired
006PROJNEW-VM   31/12/2014 05:34    Active
006PROJNEW-VM   06/01/2015 20:00    Retired
007PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
007PROJNEW-VM   27/12/2014 05:38    Active
007PROJNEW-VM   12/04/2015 19:50    Retired
008PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
008PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Active
008PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
009PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
009PROJNEW-VM   17/09/2014 20:33    Active
009PROJNEW-VM   19/02/2015 20:00    Retired
010PROJNEW-VM   11/09/2014 11:58    Retired
010PROJNEW-VM   29/10/2014 05:44    Active
010PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
011PROJNEW-VM   05/04/2015 20:00    Retired
013PROJNEW-VM   20/02/2015 20:00    Retired
014PROJNEW-VM   06/04/2015 20:00    Retired
```

Comment: you must give us an additional column (like id), becase if 2 rows have equal date, which one is latest? :)

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" row (or "next" row or "second" row), unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean exactly such column :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is the result of an query ordened by Computer Name, Date Changed all 'last' equal result on 'Date Changed' represent the real status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have, say, an `id` column that specifies the ordering, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by computername, datechanged
                                order by id desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In your particular example, all the duplicates seem to be active.  If that is the case, then:

```
select computername, datechanged,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) then min(status)
             when sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Active'
             else '***Unknown***'
        end) as status
from table t
group by computername, datechanged;
```

Comment: (I'd just be careful about a `CASE` expression that could return an integer or a string...)

Comment: Duplicate records represent the old status. eg. If the policy will change computer to retired then the first record will be active and second will be retired, but if the policy will change to active the first record will be retired and second active

Answer (score 2):

If the dates are the same, there is no first or last record, so assuming you only have those 2 statuses, and you want the status always to be `Active` when 2 rows exist at the same time, you can just do it with min:

```
select
    ComputerName
    DateChanged
    min(Status) as Status
from
    YourTable
group by
    ComputerName
    DateChanged
```

If it's more complex, you can do similar things with row_number and ordering by the desired order of statuses.